# Backup & Restore Group Policy of Workgroup Window XP

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-xp

I have around 20 system in Workgroup, I have configured a Group policy along with Administrative Template on one system.
Do you know, how to transfer this Group Policy along with Administrative template to other system, without re-configuring it manually on all other systems.

I have exported the Security setting in .inf file ( as Security Template ), but how to export setting related to Administrative template?

Comment: This got closed as off topic, though that's not how I voted, so I just wanted to leave a comment.  Which is essentially that the way you copy group policies from one machine to another is by using an Active Directory domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy local group policy between machines by copying the "%SystemRoot%\System32\GroupPolicy" directory. Beware that any policy setings that use SIDs won't "copy" between machines properly. Administrative templates, IE settings, and scripts will copy fine, though.